# Selecting objects from ant field for attribute of number lists

Tags: pyqgis

My layer contains a field 'H' which has values ​​of type list as an attribute:

```
0,1,2,5
2,1,6,1,3,0
0,0,0
...
```

I want to select objects in my layer based on attributes...

For example: to select objects that have a value of `0,0,0`
I write the following code...

```
al = iface.activeLayer()
for feature in al.getFeatures():
    t = [H]
    def filter(x):
        return x == 0
    foo = [x for x in t if filter(x)]
al.select(foo)
```

It does not return an error but does not work.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `H` is string?.

Comment: What kind of format do you use? Because some formats don't support lists as an attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select all features with `H='0,0,0'` directly using `selectByExpression` method:

```
al = iface.activeLayer()
al.selectByExpression(" H='0,0,0' ")
```